# How can I make a smooth blur?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a smooth blur as smooth as a gradient from transparent to dark?

```css
.img {
  background: url(https://4kwallpapers.com/images/walls/thumbs_2t/13551.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.img .shadow {
  content: "";
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( 360deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 100%) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

I am not sure if I understood you question correctly.

*Hover over it to see the different it makes.*

```css
.img {
  background: url(https://4kwallpapers.com/images/walls/thumbs_2t/13551.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.shadow {
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(transparent, black 80%);
  
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.img:hover .shadow {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

Combine mask with background

```css
.img {
  background: url(https://4kwallpapers.com/images/walls/thumbs_2t/13551.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.img:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  inset: auto 0 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#0000, #000 90%);
  background: linear-gradient(#0000, #0005 70%,#000);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
```

Comment: But then there's no blackout

Comment: @Vector you can always add a `background: #0005` or any semi transparent black color if you want some blackout

Comment: Something doesn’t work, can you update the code with dimming from transparent to black?

Comment: This is the result to be honest)

Comment: What is and what isn't literal?

Answer (score 6):

You could look at layering multiple elements over each other. The first layer is the tallest, least blurred, such that its blur is less discernible with the original image. We can then layer more elements on top that increase in blur but are shorter, so that the stronger blur works its way down the image. We "blend" the layers together with the `mask`.

Of course, adjust parameters to taste:

```css
.img {
  background: url(https://4kwallpapers.com/images/walls/thumbs_2t/13551.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.img .shadow {
  content: "";
  height: calc(150px * var(--n) / 4);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( 360deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 75%) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 150px);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #0000);
  mask: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #0000);
  backdrop-filter: blur(calc(10px / var(--n)));
}

.shadow:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 4;
}

.shadow:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 3;
}

.shadow:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 2;
}

.shadow:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And there is almost no blur here

Comment: Indeed, as I said, you can adjust the parameters to taste to increase the amount of blur.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) (in the code snippet, for removing the blur filter, hover on the image):

```css
img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://4kwallpapers.com/images/walls/thumbs_2t/13551.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.linear-filter-top-to-bottom {
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, transparent 100%, black);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(black, transparent 100%, black);
  -webkit-filter: blur(24px);
  mask: url("#linear-mask");
  filter: url("#filter");
}
.linear-filter-top-to-bottom:hover {
  mask: none;
  filter: none;
  -webkit-mask: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
}
.filter-border {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <img class="img-src" />
        <img class="linear-filter-top-to-bottom img-src" />
      </div>
      <svg height="0">
        <defs>
          <mask id="linear-mask">
            <rect class="filter-border" fill="url(#l1)"></rect>
            <linearGradient id="l1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
              <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="black" offset="40%" />
              <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
          </mask>
          <filter id="filter">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
          </filter>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
```